# Select canvas shapes in Konva.js for testing

Tags: konvajs

I have hundreds of shapes in canvas when onClick on a shape will take an action.

In my feature test, I am currently simulating the mouse click on a particular pixel. However, this is not ideal because the position of the graph may change. Unlike SVG, canvas doesn't expose the particular shape in the DOM. Is there a way to select the shape in a canvas by id for testing purposes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use selectors to find any node inside the stage https://konvajs.org/docs/selectors/Select_by_id.html

```js
const shape = stage.findOne('#id');
```